# How to display in the django template information of a manytomany model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I am practicing django but i am not able to display the following information from the database in the template.

I have these 3 models (PURCHASE ORDERS, MOVEMENTS, RECEIPTS):

```
class Ordenes_Compra(models.Model):
orden_compra=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
proveedor=models.ForeignKey(Proveedores, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comedor=models.ForeignKey(Centros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fecha_documento=models.DateField()
fecha_entrega=models.DateField()
class Meta():
verbose_name='Orden de compra'
verbose_name_plural="Ordenes de compra"

class Movimientos(models.Model):
movimientos = \[
('ING', 'INGRESO'),
('SAL', 'SALIDA'),
\]
estados = \[
('PRO', 'PROCESADO'),
('ANA', 'ANALIZADO'),
('PEN', 'PENDIENTE'),
('CAN', 'CANCELADO'),
\]
cantidad_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
precio_por_um=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=20)
mat_um=models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=True)
orden_compra_mov=models.ForeignKey(Ordenes_Compra,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tipo_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=movimientos, blank=True, null=True)
estado_movimiento=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=estados, blank=True, null=True)
class Meta():
verbose_name='Movimiento'
verbose_name_plural="Movimientos"

class Imagenes_Comprobantes_Moviemientos (models.Model):
imagen_factura=models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
factura=models.CharField(max_length=20)
orden_compra_imagen=models.ManyToManyField(Ordenes_Compra)
class Meta():
verbose_name='Comprobante'
verbose_name_plural="Comprobantes"
```

Each PURCHASE ORDER can have several RELATED VOUCHERS and several VOUCHERS can have different PURCHASE ORDERS.

In the template, I am going to show a table with the MOVEMENTS, from which I want to give the information of the PURCHASE ORDERS that are related to that movement and the PROOFS related to that PURCHASE ORDERS:

I was thinking of something like this, but it doesn't work and I'm totally lost in what would be the best way to obtain the information of the receipts related to the purchase order related to the movement in the template:

**THE SECOND FOR IS THE ONE IN WHICH I MAKE THE QUERY THAT WOULD NOT BE ABLE TO RESOLVE**

```
    {% for registro in movimientos %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{registro.cantidad_um|floatformat:2}}</td>
            <td>{{registro.orden_compra_mov.orden_compra}}</td>
            <td>{{registro.orden_compra_mov.comedor.nombre_centro}}</td>                  
            <td>
              {% for comprobante in registro.orden_compra_mov.orden_compra %}
                  
                  {{comprobante}}
    
              {% endfor %}
            </td>
```

Thanks for your help!

(in case it is necessary I leave the view)

```
def movimientos(request):

movimientos = Movimientos.objects.annotate(total=F('precio_por_um') \* F('cantidad_um'))

return render(request, 'app/movimientos.html', {'movimientos':movimientos})
```

Problem when wanting to see in the template data from the postgresql database of a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, the question was to access the inverse relationship through related_name.

I leave the documentation link: [DJANGO DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/)